# How can I cut a substring from a string to the end using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, url

I have a url:

```
http://localhost/40ATV/dashboard.php?page_id=projeto_lista&lista_tipo=equipe
```

I want to get the address after the last dash using javascript:

```
dashboard.php?page_id=projeto_lista&lista_tipo=equipe
```

Comment: Hi Erick, the link you shared is on your local machine so is not visible. If you rephrase your question with a simple code snippet of what you currently have, then I can attempt to answer

Comment: Will your substring always start `/dashboard...`? Edit: @Rowan, the link is just an example of the string he's trying to cut the substring from. I hope.

Comment: Haha, oops. Fail :) Listen to @Elliot – confused me as it appears as a link, natural reaction is to click

Comment: Hello. Thanks for yout reply. Makes no difference the server. I want to cut after the last "/".

Comment: JavaScript substr will do for this, no jQuery needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get substring after last specific character in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899702/how-to-get-substring-after-last-specific-character-in-javascript)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` and `substr` to get the sub-string you want:

```
//using a string variable set to the URL you want to pull info from
//this could be set to `window.location.href` instead to get the current URL
var strIn  = 'http://localhost/40ATV/dashboard.php?page_id=projeto_lista&lista_tipo=equipe',

    //get the index of the start of the part of the URL we want to keep
    index  = strIn.indexOf('/dashboard.php'),

    //then get everything after the found index
    strOut = strIn.substr(index);
```

The `strOut` variable now holds everything after `/dashboard.php` (including that string).

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DupwQ/

### UPDATE:

The `strOut` variable in the example above includes the prefixed forward slash and it was requested that the output should not.

Replacing `strOut = strIn.substr(index)` with `strOut = strIn.substr(index + 1)` fixes the output for this specific use case by starting the substring one character farther ahead in the string.

Something else you could do is search for the string after a specific search term (non-inclusive):

```
var strIn = 'http://localhost/40ATV/dashboard.php?page_id=projeto_lista&lista_tipo=equipe';
var searchTerm = '/dashboard.php?';
var searchIndex = strIn.indexOf(searchTerm);
var strOut = strIn.substr(searchIndex + searchTerm.length); //this is where the magic happens :)
```

`strOut` now holds everything after `/dashboard.php?` (non-inclusive).

Here is an updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7ud0pnmr/1/

Docs -

- `indexOf()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf
- `substr()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr
- `String.length`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length

Comment: I see many vote up, But this have two problem: 1) this included `/` char, but in the question, refer to without `/`. 2) for resolve that, if use indexOf...+1 then return all string when there are not any `/dashboard...` , so I suggestion use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58456746/1407491

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. Good catch. Answer updated to reflect the slash being included in output.

Answer (score 8):

This may be new, but the [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method returns everything from a specified index to the end of the string.

```
var string = "This is a test";

console.log(string.substring(5));
// returns "is a test"
```

Answer (score 5):

If the beginning is always "http://localhost/40ATV" you can do this:

```
var a = "http://localhost/40ATV/dashboard.php?page_id=projeto_lista&lista_tipo=equipe";
var cut = a.substr(22);
```

Comment: It may help to explain how something works at times instead of just answering the question with a utilitarian answer.  substr/substring and indexOf are all important operations that can/should be covered.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm new around here so please bare with me :)

Comment: Not a problem.. just offering advice for more constructive answers. :)

Answer (score 4):

The native JavaScript String method `substr`*<sup>[[MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)</sup>* can accomplish what you need. Just supply the starting index and omit the length parameter, and it grabs all the way to the end.

Now, how to go about getting the starting index? You didn't give any criteria, so I can't really help with that.

Comment: I don't think is so easy. substr cannot find a specific group of characteres.

Comment: Yes. For that, you would need to find the starting index.

Answer (score 2):

No need for jQuery, plain old javascript will do the job just fine.

```js
var myString = "http://localhost/40ATV/dashboard.php?page_id=projeto_lista&lista_tipo=equipe";
var mySplitResult = myString.split("\/");
document.write(mySplitResult[mySplitResult.length - 1]);​
```

and if you want the leading /

```
document.write("/" + mySplitResult[mySplitResult.length - 1]);​
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all **SPLIT** URL:

```
var str = "http://localhost/40ATV/dashboard.php?page_id=projeto_lista&lista_tipo=equipe";
var arr_split = str.split("/");
```

Find the last array:

```
var num = arr_split.length-1;
```

You get the address after the last dash:

```
alert(arr_split[num]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, if there are not `dashboard...` return empty.

```js
var str = 'http://localhost/40ATV/dashboard.php?page_id=projeto_lista&lista_tipo=equipe';
var index = str.indexOf('/dashboard.php') + 1;
var result = '';
if (index != 0) {
  result = str.substr(index);
}
console.log(result);
```