# How to get substring after last specific character in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string `test/category/1`. I have to get substring after `test/category/`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use [String.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) with [String.lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

```
var str = 'test/category/1';
str.slice(0, str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
// => "test/category/"
str.slice(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
// => 1
```

Answer (score 8):

The actual code will depend on whether you need the full prefix or the last slash. For the last slash only, see Pedro's answer. For the full prefix (and a variable PREFIX):

```
var PREFIX = "test/category/";
str.substr(str.lastIndexOf(PREFIX) + PREFIX.length);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use below snippet to get that

```
var str = 'test/category/1/4'
str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/')+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

A more complete compact ES6 function to do the work for you:

```
const lastPartAfterSign = (str, separator='/') => {
  let result = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(separator)+1)
  return result != str ? result : false
}

const input = 'test/category/1'

console.log(lastPartAfterSign(input))
//outputs "1"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = 'test/category/1';
str.substr(str.length -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "test/category/1";
pre=test/category/;
var res = str.substring(pre.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the indexOf() and slice()

```js
function after(str, substr) {
  return str.slice(str.indexOf(substr) + substr.length, str.length);
}

// Test:

document.write(after("test/category/1", "test/category/"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.substring(indexStart(, indexEnd)):

```
var str = 'test/category/1';
var ln=str.length;
alert(str.substring(ln-1,ln));
```