# How to split string of input tag HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

When a user enters the below link in an input tag, I just want the last part of the string, in order to minimize input mistakes - the two input fields generate a new link that the user can copy and use.

`name:id:5icOoE6VgqFKohjWWNp0Ac` (I just want the last '`5icOoE6VgqFKohjWWNp0Ac`' part)

Can anyone help me with amending the below to achieve this?

```js
function generateFullName() {
  document.getElementById('txtFullName').value = ('https://nlproducts.nl/item/') + document.getElementById('fName').value + ('?context=') + document.getElementById('lName').value;
}
```

```html
Enter a product ID:
<input type="text" id="fName" placeholder='0A5gdlrpAuQqZ2iFgnqBFW' />

Enter a user ID: 
<input type="text" id="lName" oninput="generateFullName()" placeholder='37i9dQZF1DXcBWIGoYBM5M'/><br/></p>

Tada! This would be the link for your campaign:
<input type="text" id="txtFullName" name="txtFullName" />
```

Comment: you mena like split(":")[2] ?

Comment: So, have you tried anything? If it's always the literal string `name:id:` before it, you could use a simple application of `substring`...

Comment: I did but I'm fairly new to HTML... it is indeed always the same literal string (and a split). Would you be able to share an example?

Comment: I'm confused as how your code example has anything to do with your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get substring after last specific character in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899702/how-to-get-substring-after-last-specific-character-in-javascript). Just replace `/` with `:`.

Comment: Would someone be able to able a string split/slice to the above mentioned code?

Comment: @BJSP I edited my answer to take into account your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JavaScript function that takes a string as input, and formats it to only keep the last part after the last colon (if it contains a colon):

```
function parseColon(txt) {
     return txt.split(":").slice(-1).pop();
}
```

Eg. `parseColon("a:b:c")` would return `"c"`

You can validate your inputs with:

```
function isValidInput(txt) {
  numberOfColons = txt.split(":").length - 1;
  if (txt.length == 32 && numberOfColons == 2) 
    return true

  return false
}
```

In your code you can use these two functions to check & parse `lName` and `fName` like this:

```js
function generateFullName() {

    var lName_val = document.getElementById('lName').value;
    var fName_val = document.getElementById('fName').value;
    
    //fill in link in the output if fName and lName are valid inputs
    if(isValidInput(fName_val) && isValidInput(lName_val))
      document.getElementById('txtFullName').value = ('https://nlproducts.nl/item/') + parseColon(fName_val) + ('?context=') + parseColon(lName_val); 
    // otherwise, clear the output field
    else
      document.getElementById('txtFullName').value = "";
}

function parseColon(txt) {
  // return the part after the last colon
  return txt.split(":").slice(-1).pop();
}

function isValidInput(txt) {
  numberOfColons = txt.split(":").length - 1;
  if (txt.length == 38 && numberOfColons == 2) 
    return true
    
  return false
}
```

```html
Enter a product ID:<br>
<input type="text" id="fName" oninput="generateFullName()" placeholder='0A5gdlrpAuQqZ2iFgnqBFW' size="50"/><br/>

Enter a user ID:<br>
<input type="text" id="lName" oninput="generateFullName()" placeholder='37i9dQZF1DXcBWIGoYBM5M' size="50"/><br/><br/>

Tada! This would be the link for your campaign:<br>
<input type="text" id="txtFullName" name="txtFullName" size="50"/>
```

Comment: how would you make sure you only get an output whenever the input matches 36 characters (and 2x ":") and not just fills in whatever text you put into lName or fName?

Comment: @BJSP I edited my answer to include input validation. I assume you mean 36 characters + 2 colons so 38 characters in total.